# Display PDF like on web

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display PDF file on the web without download option and copy option.

Then I found this https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kwBvDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Can you tell me how can I achieve this on my website?

Comment: If you do not want people to copy your stuff, don't put it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

What mplungjan said in his comment is correct. Anything that is put on the web can be copied one way or another. It appears that the google site you linked to is just showing an image of each page (see https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=kwBvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0s8V3HjcApLeNwIGStMQlzZFaotA) with transparent pixels over each image to make it so you can't right-click to save the image. But it's easy to see what they're doing by viewing the source in the inspector.

If you don't want your users to be able to download the entire file, you could break it up into multiple small files (or images, like google is doing in your link) that would make it a little harder for them to get the files. But you can't really stop them from downloading anything.